# Communication with Thorlabs uc480 camera

Tags: python, usb

I was able to get the current image from a Thorlabs uc480 camera using `instrumental`. My issue is when I try to adjust the parameters for `grab_image`. I can change `cx` and `left` to any value and get an image. But `cy` and top only works if `cy=600` and `top=300`. The purpose is to create a GUI so that the user can select values for these parameters to zoom in/out an image.

Here is my code

```
import instrumental
from instrumental.drivers.cameras import uc480
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

paramsets = instrumental.list_instruments()
cammer = instrumental.instrument(paramsets[0])

plt.figure()
framer= cammer.grab_image(timeout='1s',copy=True,n_frames=1,exposure_time='5ms',cx=640,
                                      left=10,cy=600,top=300)
plt.pcolormesh(framer)
```

The above code does not give an image if I choose `cy=600` and `top=10`. Are there any particular value set to be used for these parameters? How can I get an image of the full sensor size?

Answer (score 0):

Thorlabs has a Python programming interface available as a download on their website. It is very well documented, and can be installed locally via pip.

Link:
https://www.thorlabs.com/software_pages/ViewSoftwarePage.cfm?Code=ThorCam

Here is an example of a simple capture algorithm that might help get you started:

```
    from thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_camera import TLCameraSDK
    from thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_mono_to_color_processor import MonoToColorProcessorSDK
    from thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_camera_enums import SENSOR_TYPE

    # open the TLCameraSDK dll
    with TLCameraSDK() as sdk:
        cameras = sdk.discover_available_cameras()
        if len(cameras) == 0:
            print("Error: no cameras detected!")

    with sdk.open_camera(cameras[0]) as camera:
        #camera.disarm() # ensure any previous session is closed
        #  setup the camera for continuous acquisition
        camera.frames_per_trigger_zero_for_unlimited = 0
        camera.image_poll_timeout_ms = 2000  # 2 second timeout
        camera.arm(2)


        # need to save the image width and height for color processing
        image_width = camera.image_width_pixels
        image_height = camera.image_height_pixels

        # initialize a mono to color processor if this is a color camera
        is_color_camera = (camera.camera_sensor_type == SENSOR_TYPE.BAYER)
        mono_to_color_sdk = None
        mono_to_color_processor = None
        if is_color_camera:
            mono_to_color_sdk = MonoToColorProcessorSDK()
            mono_to_color_processor = mono_to_color_sdk.create_mono_to_color_processor(
                camera.camera_sensor_type,
                camera.color_filter_array_phase,
                camera.get_color_correction_matrix(),
                camera.get_default_white_balance_matrix(),
                camera.bit_depth
            )

        # begin acquisition
        camera.issue_software_trigger()
        
        # get the next frame
        frame = camera.get_pending_frame_or_null()
        
        # initialize frame attempts and max limit
        frame_attempts = 0 
        max_attempts = 10

        # if frame is null, try to get a frame until
        # successful or until max_attempts is reached
        if frame is None:
            
            while frame is None:
                frame = camera.get_pending_frame_or_null()
                frame_attempts += 1

                if frame_attempts == max_attempts:
                    raise TimeoutError("Timeout was reached while polling for a frame, program will now exit")

        image_data = frame.image_buffer
        if is_color_camera:

            # transform the raw image data into RGB color data
            color_data = mono_to_color_processor.transform_to_24(image_data, image_width, image_height) 
            save_data = np.reshape(color_data,(image_height, image_width,3))            


        camera.disarm()
```

You can also process the image after capture with the PIL library.